# Почему место - лобное?

Tags: этимология

Лобное место - иначе эшафот, место казни. А почему оно называется лобным? При чем тут лоб?
Заранее спасибо за разъяснения

Answer (score 3):

Из «Краткого церковнославянского словаря»:
Лобное место 
- гора Голгофа, называемая лобным местом потому, что по преданию здесь был погребен Адам, и лоб его, т.е. голова, освятилась кровью Спасителя